# Pass parameters var/value to second page Php

Tags: php, variables, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass some parameters vars and variables from one page **x** to another page **y**

My parameterized portion looks like:

```
x?path=1&edu=4&cert=
```

How can I pass these values easily to another page using php?

Note: often times `cert` var has no value.

For example:
I have a file `x.php` that is generating a url like: `xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/p?path=1&edu=4&cert=` . I need to then use this `url` in `y.php` - how can I do this?

Note: I am unable to use a framework for this application

Thanks

Comment: You can use `$_SESSION` ?!

Comment: You're already passing them by doing that. To access them, you can do things like:

    $edu = $_GET['edu'];

Or use whatever your framework supplies, if you're using one.

Comment: I dont think you're understanding. Those values are already parameterized, im now trying to use these var/values in a different php page - does that make sense?

Comment: nope, it doesn't. Show us what URI loads what PHP, and what you want to do in that PHP file, what you tried (look into `$_GET`, or better, `filter_var`)

Comment: So, I have x.php that is generating a url like: https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/p?path=1&edu=4&cert= . I need to then use this url in y.php - any better?

Comment: @CodeTalk That's correct.

Comment: @Mike - unfortunately this application isnt written with a framework, although id love to have it

Comment: y.php is local php file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When receiving the parameters in page x, save them in variables and add them in the link to the page y. There are better ways but they depend on exactly what you want to do. 
Simple example below.

x.php?path=1&edu=4&cert=

```
<?php
    $path=$_GET['path'];
    $edu=$_GET['edu'];
    $cert=$_GET['cert'];
    $params = "?path=".$path."&edu=".$edu."&cert=".$cert;
?>
<a href="y.php<?php echo $params ?>">Link to page Y with params obtained from page X</a>
```

The result will be y.php?path=1&edu=4&cert=

It doesn't matter if you don't have a value in cert, it will pass as cert=

Answer (score 0):

try use header location

```
$path=$_GET['path'];
$edu=$_GET['edu'];
if(!isset($_GET['cert'])) header("Location: y.php?edu={$edu}&path={$path}"); 
else $cert = $_GET['cert'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to understand what you want but try this :

### x.php

```
<?php

$url = 'http:localhost/test.php?path=1&edu=4&cert=';//generated url
parse_str(parse_url($url)['query']);//get parameter on url
include("y.php");
```

### y.php

```
<?php

//!\ you must secure this value /!\
var_dump($path);
var_dump($edu);
var_dump($cert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are u submitting any form???If you are going from x.php to y.php through some event like button click then you can do an ajax call and easily can receive the parameters in the other page.
like `<input name="" type="button" onclick="showHint($x);" value="click on me!" id="start" />//wher $x=1 your value`

```
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

You can write function as

```
<script>
function showHint(path) {

if (path.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "y.php?p=" + path, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


 }
</script>`
```

Now in y.php you can catch the param as

```
$path= $_REQUEST["p"];
```

Like this you can pass the params from one php page to another.
I don't know whether you want this kind of thing or something else.